# Is it possible to access a shared note via the evernote SDK?

Tags: evernote

I'm wondering if its possible to access a note from the Evernote SDK that a user has shared publicly based on its URL?

Obviously you can pull the page itself down without the API, and you can't write to it either way, but I was wondering if it was possible to get a readonly copy via the API so that you could get the note data without having to attempt an unreliable screen scrape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. The shared note url is of the format : hostname/shard/shardId/notGUID/noteKey .

1. You can parse this URL, to get all the fields separated out. Then, use [authenticateToSharedNote](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_authenticateToSharedNote) API.
2. You can then use the [AuthenticationResult](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/UserStore.html#Struct_AuthenticationResult) to create a note store :

   sharedNoteStoreUrl = AuthenticationResult.noteStoreURL;

   TBinaryProtocol sharedNoteStoreProt = new TBinaryProtocol(new     THttpClient(sharedNoteStoreUrl));

   NoteStore.Client sharedNoteStore = new NoteStore.Client(sharedNoteStoreProt,sharedNoteStoreProt);
3. You can then access the note with the [getNote](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNote) API, using the auth token from step 2.

Comment: awesome, that looks exactly like what I want.  Thanks!